# Python how to add "0." in-front of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a python program and I need it to add "0." in front of the users' input.

For example:
the user types 65
then the program outputs a float 0.65

Comment: `float('0.' + input())`? Note that you'll have to implement error checking in the case the user enters invalidinput.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
input = 65
output = float('0.' + str(input))
print(output)
```

Comment: I tried this before but it outputs it as a string, and I need the output to be a float

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input('Please enter a number: ')
if not user_input.isdecimal():
    raise TypeError('Not a decimal.')
new_float = float('0.' + user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
digits = len(str(user_input))
output = user_input / (10 ** digits)
print(output)
```

Assuming you are getting an integer: you must count number of digits in it and divide it by the 10 in the power of number of digits.

Let me explain by steps:

- You got 65
- 65 has 2 digits in it
- 10 to the power of 2: 10^2 = 100
- Then we divide 65 by 100 and get 0.65